# Why are extension methods used extensively in LINQ, despite the framework's guidelines?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, extension-methods

The [Extension Methods documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb383977.aspx) says:

> For a class library that you implemented, you shouldn't use extension
>   methods to avoid incrementing the version number of an assembly.

So why has the .NET team used them extensively in Enumerable and Queryable?

In search of a reason I checked out my copy of *C# In Depth*, where I came away with a feeling that extension methods are used because:

- You can chain them together in a readable way
- You can bring them in and out of scope

Is this correct or are the .NET team flying in the face of their own documentation? Are there other reasons that justify their use?

Comment: The whole sentence is "For a class library that you implemented, you shouldn't use extension methods *to avoid incrementing the version number of an assembly.*" Cutting it off the way it's quoted in this question looses the context and changes the meaning.

Comment: Cutting it off is misleading. Adding a period *that isn't there in the quoted text* to indicate the end of the sentence isn't just misleading, it's lying.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is based on a faulty premise, specifically, a mis-quoted excerpt.

Comment: It does say use them sparingly.  Extend to an already existing class to make your life easier.  If you are writing a new class library you should't need them.  Make sure you've got all your functionality covered on the off.  Sometime in the future if you think of something new you want to add and don't want to change the existing class, then consider using them.  That's sparingly.  I thought that's what they were about. More of a hind-sight thing for your libraries or an aid to extend the BCL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because LINQ works on `IEnumerable`, not any specific implementation of a collection. If they were part of the definition of `IEnumerable`, you would have to implement your own methods, and it would needlessly bloat the interface. By putting LINQ into extension methods, you can implement `IEnumerable` on any class you create yourself, and the existing LINQ methods will work on it.

Answer (score 5):

That's not the entire sentence.  What is actually written is this:

> For a class library that you implemented, you shouldn't use extension methods **to avoid incrementing the version number of an assembly**. If you want to add significant functionality to a library for which you own the source code, you should follow the standard .NET Framework guidelines for assembly versioning.

(emphasis added)

What this means is that you should avoid just adding extension methods to a class when you're adding large amounts of functionality, just for the sake of not incrementing the assembly version.  If you're going to introduce large amounts of new functionality, you should really do it in a new version of that assembly.